# How to change the colors of legends markers in the given code?

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I am using this code

```
h := Cos[3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x;
g := Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[ 3 x])/(2 x);
F := -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) -  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[ 3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x)^2];
W := -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) +  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[ 3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x)^2];
pl := Plot[2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5},  AxesLabel -> {"x", " "}];

 With[{rat =  F /. {{f_ :> f}, {r : Sqrt[_] :> -r}} // Apply@Times // Expand // 
    Simplify, F = F, g = g,  rat2 = W /. {{s_ :> s}, {q : Sqrt[_] :> -q}} // Apply@Times //  Expand // Simplify, W = W},

Manipulate[ 
Show[

pl, 

Normal@Plot[   1   , {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5}, PlotPoints -> 200, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ {x, rat}}, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
PlotLegends -> "\[FilledSmallCircle]  RedPoint"] /. 
Point[p_] :> Point[p /. {x_Real, z_Real} :> {x, 1.5}] // 
DeleteCases[#, Point[{x0_, _}] /;  Abs[F /. x -> x0] > 0.1 || Abs[g^2 - 1 /. x -> x0] < 0.01 , Infinity] &,

Normal@Plot[   1    , {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5}, PlotPoints -> 200, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ {x, rat2}}, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
PlotLegends -> "\[FilledSmallCircle]  BluePoint"] /. Point[p_] :> Point[p /. {x_Real, z_Real} :> {x, 1.5}] // 
DeleteCases[#,  Point[{x0_, _}] /;  Abs[W /. x -> x0] > 0.1 || Abs[g^2 - 1 /. x -> x0] < 0.01 , 
 Infinity] &]
  
, {y, -4, 0}  ]]
```

and I get

[image]

> **Question**.  How can I change those black points in legends from black to red and blue (as shown in the picture)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
PlotLegends -> "\[FilledSmallCircle]  RedPoint"
```

by

```
PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{Red}, {"RedPoint"}]
```

and similarly for the blue point.

Comment: Thanks. I have another related question: if I use some special characters as the legend, say *, +, ..., then, is it possible to have them in color form?

Comment: Try `Style["+", Red]`.